# SQLAlchemy : how to apply distinct before a filter in a join query

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to apply distinct before filtering in a join query ?

I have 2 tables :

```
class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)

class Event(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
  description = db.Column(db.String(80))
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
  user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('events', lazy=True))
```

I want to select all users where the **most recent** event description is empty.

I thought this would work:

```
User.query.join('events').order_by(Event.date).distinct(User.id).filter(Event.description==None)
```

However, it seems that distinct is called after filter. Is there a way to force to apply distinct before filtering ?

Answer (score 1):

[DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) is used to return different values.

In this case you need a subquery to create a table using [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) where you group `Event` by `user_id` and calculating the most recent event :

```
last_events = db.session.query(
                    Event.user_id, 
                    db.func.max(Event.date).label('last_event_date'),
                    Event.description)\
                        .group_by(Event.user_id)
                        .subquery()
```

Then you can join this table to `User` and filter on the last_event_description :

```
User.query.join(last_events,User.id==last_events.c.bac_id)
            .filter(last_events.c.description==None)
```

Et voilà !

The `.c` comes from the way you access the columns of the subquery in SQLAlchemy.